# Difference Between 2 variables lists TIBCO BW

Tags: xpath, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have 2 variables.
I need to get the difference between them.
$var (a,b,c,d) and $var2 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g).
How can i do this using xpath funtions?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are a, b, c, d, etc? Are they nodes, or something else? Is a "c" in the first list to be considered the same as a "c" in the second list, or might they be different elements, both named "c"? If so, what determines whether they are to be considered "the same"? Are you concerned with the order of the lists, e.g. is (a,b,c) the same as (b,c,a)? This question needs much more careful specification.

Answer (score 1):

If tibco supports XPath 2.0, you can try using `except` and union (`|`) like so :

```
$var except $var2 | $var2 except $var
```

Answer (score 1):

With XPATH 1.0 you can also use the union off diffs of nodesets ([O'Reilly's XSLT Cookbook](http://users.atw.hu/xsltcookbook2/xsltckbk2-chp-1-sect-7.html))

Elements from var not in var1: `$var[count(. | $var1) != count($var1)]`
Elements from var1 not in var: `$var1[count(. | $var) != count($var)]`

Therefor try:

```
$var[count(. | $var1) != count($var1)] | $var1[count(. | $var) != count($var)]
```